# How to extract Coq's Z into Haskell's Integer

Tags: coq, coq-extraction

I'm trying to extract to Haskell a program in Coq that uses `Z` numbers. I want to map Coq's Z to Haskell's Integer.

I found some [libraries](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.3/stdlib/index_library_E.html) for doing that aiming OCaml, but not aiming Haskell.
There is no library for that?

I need the extractions (found [here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.3/stdlib/Coq.extraction.ExtrOcamlZBigInt.html)):

```
Extract Inductive positive => "Big.big_int"
 [ "Big.doubleplusone" "Big.double" "Big.one" ] "Big.positive_case".

Extract Inductive Z => "Big.big_int"
 [ "Big.zero" "" "Big.opp" ] "Big.z_case".

Extract Inductive N => "Big.big_int"
 [ "Big.zero" "" ] "Big.n_case".
```

but aiming Haskell.

I'll just ask: how to do it?.

But secondly, I should say why I couldn't do it myself:

I guess I can't come up with that myself possibly because I'm misunderstanding somethings, for example: why there is a empty string in the second definition? The definition of `Z` has three constructors: `Z0`, `Zpos` and `Zneg`. I don't see how `"Big.zero" "" "Big.opp"` is related with this.

Also, I didn't understand how the last string works: "...a final extra string that indicates how to perform pattern-matching over this inductive type." (found in [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/addendum/extraction.html?highlight=extract%20inductive#realizing-inductive-types)).

The chapter [Extraction](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Extraction.html#lab378) of S.F. says that "we give an OCaml expression that can be used as a "recursor" over elements of the type. (Think Church numerals.)".

How the code bellow is a recursor or does pattern-maching?

```
  "(fun zero succ n →
      if n=0 then zero () else succ (n-1))".
```

After I understand those things, I hope that I can create, myself, the extractions that I may ever need.

Comment: You might want to take a peek at [extraction.v](https://github.com/antalsz/hs-to-coq/blob/832e281e98685cd4d2914fb62a475476d1d86fa4/core-semantics-no-values/extraction.v) of [hs-to-coq](https://github.com/antalsz/hs-to-coq).

Comment: you linked to the Coq v8.3 documentation - is that the version you're using? In that case you'll have to write the extraction commands yourself.

Comment: @TejChajed no, it's not. For some reason that was the documentation that I found. Search skills fault.

Comment: Not your fault! The Coq documentation can be quite hard to Google for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just import `ExtrHaskellZInteger` ([documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.extraction.ExtrHaskellZInteger.html)).